# Unrecognized commands in bash are captured by the python interpreter

Tags: python, bash

Every time I try to invoke a command that does not exist (`$ a`, for example) in the console (/bin/bash) the interpreter waits for a long time. And when I interrupt it (^C), I get a error message from Python interpreter. Instead of that, I expect it to tell me that the command was unrecognized. Why is this happening?

```
$ a
^C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
root@dell:/home/antonio/workspace/biz_index#     from encodings import aliases
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.py", line 17, in <module>
    """
KeyboardInterrupt
^C
```

Comment: What's in your `PATH`?

Comment: What is the result of `which a`?

Comment: Does this only happen in a certain directory, or everywhere? It's likely that you have accidentally shadowed a builtin Python package with some of your own code.

Comment: My PATH is:  
/home/antonio/.local/bin:/home/antonio/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: This appears to be off topic for StackOverflow. I think Unix/Linux is probably the best site to migrate to, but possibly SuperUser would be better?

Comment: a does not exist. Because of that I get this strange behaviour. There is nothing for the exit of which a.

Comment: It happens everywhere.

Comment: @AntonioRomero Check every directory in your `PATH` and see if any of them contain any .py files. Also, try `export PATH=""`, try an invalid command again, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @PatrickCollins when I export an empty PATH it is all correctly. I have under  /home/antonio/.local/bin only nodejs modules but no py files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If setting `PATH=""` fixes it, then something, somewhere is shadowing a python package that is getting called by the `command-not-found` package. I recently did this myself by writing a script called `struct.py`. You need to go through every directory in your path, i.e.

```
/home/antonio/.local/bin
/home/antonio/.local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin‌​
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
```

and look for `.py` files there. One of them shares a name with one of the builtin Python packages. Alternatively, you can remove directories from your `PATH` and add them back in until you find out which one breaks it. Once you find it, you need to delete it or rename it.

Here's a shell one-liner to do it for you:

```
for dir in $(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"); do ls -1 $dir | grep "[.]py"; done
```

You can test this out in your own shell by trying the following (recreating my mistake from a few days ago):

```
echo 'print("HELLO WORLD")' >> struct.py
```

Now in my shell, staying in the current directory, I see:

```
➜  client git:(master) ✗ a
HELLO WORLD
zsh: command not found: a
```

Presumably the Python script that is doing the shadowing in your case is doing something more resource-intensive than just printing "HELLO WORLD", hence the hanging.

Answer (score 16):

Are you on an ubuntu machine? Ubuntu has a [command-not-found package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/command-not-found) which is implemented in python, you may have interrupted that.

In your path, there may be a script with the same name as one called by the `command-not-found` package. If there is, this script is likely the one doing the hanging. To print your path in a readable way, run `echo $PATH | tr -s ':' '\n'`.

Comment: Yes, it is Ubuntu. How can I fix it, then?

Comment: @AntonioRomero I agree my answer doesn't address the hanging. Investigating as we speak...